# changing square pattern with changing text using css?

Tags: jquery, html, css

recently, i was trying to make changing square pattern with changing text like that in www.tffchallenge.com but i am not able to find a way to do the same thing. i am just able to make a background using css without any effect.

This is my code so far :

css :

```
div {
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/YE8pcYR.jpg") fixed;
    opacity: 0.1;
    height: 6vw;
    width: 6vw;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
body {
    background: #222;
    line-height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

javascript :

```
var fadeintime = 400;
var fadeouttime = 2000;
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(anim, 50);
});
function anim(){
    var rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*$("body").children("div").length));
    var el = $("body").children("div")[rand];
    $(el).animate({opacity: "0.7"}, fadeintime);
    $(el).animate({opacity: "0.1"}, fadeouttime);
}
```

and html is :

```
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div>...
```

i have created the changing square pattern but i am unable to create changing text over it can you show me how to do it.

Comment: could you show your html too please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something to start with - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/W4sTA/2/).

I haven't figured out the problem with the placement of the letter - I'll continue to play until I get the answer. You can expand the number of letters in the array as you see fit.

JS

```
var fadeintime = 400;
var fadeouttime = 2000;
setInterval(anim, 100);
var letterarray = new Array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J');

function anim(){
    var rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*$("body").children("div").length));
    var randletter = Math.floor(Math.random() * letterarray.length);

    var el = $("body").children("div")[rand];
    $(el).animate({opacity: "0.7"}, fadeintime);
    $(el).animate({opacity: "0.1"}, fadeouttime);
    $(el).html( letterarray[randletter] );
}
```

Comment: I changed the CSS from inline-block to float: left and it got rid of the space at the top of the boxes during the first iteration. Can't figure out why it's there, but clearly it was related to display: inline-block.

Comment: but i want to have changing sentences like in tffchallenge.com and not changing alphabets above the squares.

Comment: Ok, so I've given you a start. Do you think you can parse a sentence in javascript and put the letters in an array like I did above?

Comment: i am not able to do it and can you tell me why other divs in my html are also blinking like that of squares and how can i change it?

Comment: In your CSS you refer only to 'div' - that means that your CSS/JS refers to every div on the page. If you put them in a div with a class like "holder", and you write '.holder div' - only the divs in the .holder div will be affected.